# NBA Draft - Are there any restrictions on signing an undrafted player?

Tags: nba, draft

If a played goes undrafted, are there any restrictions on where he can sign?  Can any team sign him without penalty?

Example scenario:

- Lonzo Ball wants to sign with the Golden State Warriors
- But Golden State doesn't have any picks
- Before the draft Ball makes clear that he will not sign with other teams
- The General Managers each decide that they don't need the trouble, and nobody selects him

After the Draft, can Golden State sign him?  Are there any restrictions/penalties to prevent players or teams from doing this?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, a truly undrafted player can sign with anyone.

However, your scenario is never going to happen - even if a player states that they'd only play for one team, it's still advantageous for another team to draft them (at which point they have exclusive rights to the player) and then trade them. If an acknowledged good player like Lonzo Ball went through the entire draft without being drafted, there's clearly some collusion going on, and the commissioner is going to get involved *really* quickly.